# Prune npm cache to only packages required by most recent install?

Tags: npm, npm-install, npm-ci

I would like to cache npm dependencies in a file in my Continuous Integration so that subsequent `npm ci` invocations are fast. Also, when dependencies slightly change, I would like `npm ci` to be pretty fast by reusing the cached dependencies from the previous build, and then store the cache with only the most recently used dependencies (without old unused dependencies). Is there a way to prune the npm cache to only the files that were used in the most recent `npm ci`?

I see that GitHub’s [actions/setup-node](https://github.com/actions/setup-node) stores the `~/.npm` HTTP cache in GitHub’s cache, but since the `primaryKey` of the `cache.restoreCache` call is based on the hash of `package-lock.json`, the entirety of `~/.npm` is regenerated if `package-lock.json` is even slightly changed ([cache-restore.ts](https://github.com/actions/setup-node/blob/v3.6.0/src/cache-restore.ts#L39)). In contrast, I would like to use the previous `~/.npm` as the starting point even if it has slightly different dependencies.

I also saw a blog post, [“Super fast npm install on Github Actions” by Selwyn](https://www.voorhoede.nl/en/blog/super-fast-npm-install-on-github-actions/) which uses a liberal `restore-keys` parameter to `actions/cache` to reuse the previous `~/.npm` directory even when `package-lock.json` changes. However, it appears that this solution fetches the old `~/.npm` cache but does not prune the `~/.npm` cache to only the recently used entries, so it will accumulate new versions of a dependency and not delete old versions. I would like a solution that prunes the cache to the entries that are needed by the current build.

Feel free to give an answer for `pnpm` or `yarn` too if there is an answer.